# Every $n$-ball is convex

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that every $n$-ball is convex. Let $B(a;r)$ be an $n$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with center $a$ and radius $r$. What I need to show is that for all $x,y \in B(a;r)$ we have $\theta x + (1-\theta)y \in B(a;r)$ where $0 < \theta < 1$.

Since I know $||x-a||< r/2$ and $||y-a||<r/2$, I need to show that $||\theta x + (1-\theta)y - a|| < r$. Then $||\theta x + (1-\theta)y - a|| \leq \theta ||x-y|| + ||y-a|| < \theta r + r/2$. This inequality will be less than $r$ if $\theta \leq 1/2$.

But with $\theta > 1/2$, I'm not sure how to proceed. Could someone give me a hint or suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: How do you know $||x-a||\le r/2$?

Comment: @StefanH.: I interpreted $||x-a||$ as the distance between $x$ and $a$. Since $a$ is the center and $r$ is the radius, the distance between any point and the center must be at most $r/2$.

Comment: No, the distance between any point and the center is less than $r$.

Comment: @StefanH.: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the moment, assume that $a=0$. We have $||tx+(1-t)y||\le||tx||+||(1-t)y||=|t|\cdot||x||+|(1-t)|\cdot||y||$. This follows by the triangle inequality and the homogeneity of the norm. Since $t$ and $1-t$ are positive, this is the same as $t||x||+(1-t)||y||$. Let $m$ denote the maximum of $||x||$ and $||y||$. Then $t||x||+(1-t)||y||\le tm+(1-t)m=m<r.$

This shows that the $r$-ball around the origin is convex. The see it for $B(a;r)$, write $tx+(1-t)y-a$ as $tx+(1-t)y-ta-(1-t)a=t(x-a)+(1-t)(y-a)$. Now apply the result to deduce that the norm of $tx+(1-t)y-a$ is less than $r$.

Comment: I don't really see how that helps. Is the center $a$ involved? And I would think that $0<t<1$ would be important which is a fact that hasn't been used yet in your inequality.

Comment: Could you explain your hint?

Comment: How do you know that $m=\max\{||x||, ||y|| \} < r$?

Comment: Wait are you considering a ball centered at the origin with radius $r$?

Comment: Very clever solution. I see it is enough to just consider a ball at the origin. If it isn't, it would be possible to subtract and move an open ball centered at the origin.